# What does BST mean?

Tags: terminology, fire-emblem-heroes

I played FE Sacred Stones, Blazing Sword and Blinding Blade (until ch13) before playing FE Heroes. I can't wait for Tana to be out on FEH.

Anyways, I've been checking guides on Gamepress on tiers and stuff and they mention that some heroes have "Low BST".

I may not have looked hard enough but I couldn't find any place explaining what it is. I haven't read about it in League of Legends or other games I've played either.

My best guess is "Burst" but I don't think there's much point in removing just 2 letters.

Answer (score 9):

From what I've read in several pages I guess the BST is some kind of internal value the game assigns to a character to quantify it's potential. Allowing to establish some kind of balance for the Arena and other multiplayer game modes.

[This is the link](http://feheroes.ziss.tv/index.php?title=Should_You_Pull:_Fighting_Ursula) that helped me the most on understanding this. Since I'm not able to find an oficial description of the concept I would suggest to wait for a more accurate answer.

**Edit:**

Just found out [this page](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/204447-fire-emblem-heroes/75055807) where explains how the Arena and some of it's mechanics actually works and mentions the BST:

> Once you master winning 7 Advanced battles at max level without any of
>   your units dying; the only way to increase your Offense score is by
>   using units with a higher stat total. Sometimes called BST (Base Stat
>   Total) for short.

Also in this page is included [a link to a list where you can check the BST of each character](https://fireemblem.gamewith.jp/article/show/51344). The web page appears to be in japanese but it includes the characters portraits.

Comment: @Seiyial `I would suggest to wait for a more accurate answer` I guess we've waited long enough...

Answer (score 6):

To summarize, a unit's BST (Base Stat Total) in Fire Emblem Heroes is the total value of his/her total stats in the game. For example, Lucina's neutral stats are 43/34/36/25/19, giving her a BST of 157. Keep in mind that the game does not factor in the might of the weapon (in Lucina's case, Falchion with a might of 16) into the total BST.

EDIT:
Last thing, the BST of your four units also affect how many points you recieve when playing an arena match, as mentioned by the user before me.

Answer (score -4):

Based on the previous answer and the list of levels where the term BST is mentioned. I support the idea that BST is Base State Total, which is no more than an average of the basic statistics of the characters, if you look at the list of levels in which it is set "BST Low", which are usually in intermediate or low levels, Ie they may excel in some aspects (ATK, DEF, SPD ...) or have some good skill, but their set of statistics is not good and ends up being poor in any of these statistics.